# We get the error "Task is currently locked by a running workflow" for a specific list in the site

Tags: workflow, workflow-tasks-list

We have an approval workflow on a list where we keep getting the error called "Task is currently locked by a running workflow" and it does allow the tasks to be Approved.

This happens only one specific list in the whole SharePoint farm. It starts in the afternoon and the it takes very long to get unlocked.

The list and log list the workflow uses are very huge and I am starting to think if this is causing the problem.